# How to get value from span

Tags: jquery

using jquery, how get span's value (i need the value B4 and A4) when i click on the link whith class "data-permesso" ?

```
<td>
    <div>
        <span class="day">01</span><span class="turno"><span>B4</span><span>A4</span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Box190701">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a data-permesso="190701" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">inserisci/modifica</span></a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Add `id` or `name` or other data attribute to them, so you can select them.

Comment: In your code `data-permesso` is not a class, it's `data` attr.

Comment: yes i wrong i would say attribute. Thank for suggest

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways you can get the text (we don't call value of span we call it text):
here is one of them:

```
    $('a[data-permesso]').click(function(){
        $('.turno').children('span').each(function (idx) {
            alert('index' + idx + ', text: ' + $(this).text());
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should actually accept the answer and upvote too.
If this is not the correct answer then elaborate (explain more) your question.